# Execution failed for task ':tflite_flutter_helper:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, dart, tflite

I am getting this error with **tflite_flutter_helper: ^0.3.1** and its earlier versions too.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

i've tried older kotlin versions too

error log

```
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite_flutter_helper-0.3.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\tfliteflutter\tflite_flutter_helper\TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin.kt: (43, 1): Class 'TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
    e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite_flutter_helper-0.3.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\tfliteflutter\tflite_flutter_helper\TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin.kt: (143, 2): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':tflite_flutter_helper:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > Compilation error. See log for more details
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: I have similar problem but i can not fix it, are you fixed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see this github comment to fix it:

https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_helper/issues/57#issuecomment-1128960033